# Why am I unable to fetch data from a JSON file in Chrome, while it's possible in Firefox?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a drop down list where it's values are stored in a JSON file.
I am capable of fetching the data from the file in Firefox, but am not able to do the same in Chrome, or other browsers.

Here is my HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>angularjs phone number validation</title>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ProductCntrl">
Type of Employeement:<select ng-model="initialProduct"  ng-options="p.name for p in Products"></select>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('ProductCntrl', function ($scope,$http) {

      $http.get('json1/student.json') //reading the studentRecord.json file
            .success (function(json1){
                $scope.Products = json1; // binding the json1 to the $scope                          variable
                console.log($scope.Products[0].id);
              $scope.initialProduct = $scope.Products[0];
        });  
      });
```

`json1` is the folder name and `student.json` is the file where I have stored the json data.

This my JSON file:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Salaried"

  }, {
   "id": 2,
    "name": "Apprenticeship"

  }]
```

Comment: Try clearing your chrome's and cookies

Comment: I even tried that also  but  its working ....

Answer (score 1):

Chrome enforces stricter web security. If you'd like to allow this in Chrome, you can start Chrome with the following flags: `--disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files`. Keep in mind that you should **not** run Chrome with these flags for regular browsing.

Alternatively (perhaps preferably), you could start a local web server. Python makes a good choice for this with it's SimpleHTTPServer module:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Comment: Where should i disable the web security?

Comment: That depends on what operating system you're on. If it's Windows, then you can make a new shortcut and add it to the end of the executable. If you're on Linux or OSX, you can open Chrome with the flags at the end of the executable command.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are just opening the index.html directly in your browser and not running a webserver correct? In your console you should be seeing an error like:
"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Trying running something like http-server and then opening the file.

If you have npm installed you can run:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

From the command line in the root of you project run:

```
http-server
```

Once finished simply type the following in your browser address bar. Now it works in Chrome.

```
 http://localhost:8080/
```